How to stop walking bits (direction = least to most significant bit) after getting to the chain of 0's?
I have these two functions to walk the 32 bits of an integer in TypeScript:
export function* walkBitsFromLSB(n: number) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    // Check the least significant bit (LSB)
    const bit = (n >> i) & 1
    yield bit
  }
}

export function* walkBitsFromMSB(n: number) {
  // Start with a mask that isolates the MSB of a 32-bit integer
  let mask = 1 << 31
  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    // Apply the mask to n and check if the result is non-zero
    const bit = n & mask ? 1 : 0
    yield bit
    // Shift the mask right for the next bit
    mask >>>= 1
  }
}

I can modify the MSB one to only walk the "relevant" bits, like this:
export function* walkRelevantBitsFromMSB(n: number) {
  let mask = 1 << 31;
  let start = false; // Flag to indicate when we've found the first non-zero bit
  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    const bit = n & mask ? 1 : 0;
    if (bit === 1) start = true;
    if (start) yield bit; // Only start yielding bits after the first 1 is encountered
    mask >>>= 1;
  }
}

How can you do the same for the LSB function in a somewhat optimal way?
That is, if the bits were 0b00000000000000000001111011101101, you would read:
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
DONE

How could you do this without create a cache/hashmap storing { [binaryNumber]: length } or any sort of hashtable like that. How can you simply derive it from the input n to the function, the length at which you stop checking for values?

Math.ceil(Math.log2(n))

export function* walkRelevantBitsFromLSB(n: number) {
  while (n !== 0) {
    yield n & 1;
    n >>>= 1;
  }
}

